# Inherited has no attribute X after using `attr`

Tags: python, inheritance, python-attrs

The following snippet runs fine:

```
class base:
    @classmethod
    def func(cls):
        cls.params

class inherited(base):
    params = 2
    def my_func(self):
        inherited.func()

obj = inherited()
obj.my_func()
```

However, when I add `attr`:

```
import attr

class base:
    @classmethod
    def func(cls):
        cls.params

@attr.s
class inherited(base):
    params = attr.ib()
    def my_func(self):
        inherited.func()

obj = inherited(2)
obj.my_func()
```

it now gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    obj.my_func()
  File "test.py", line 13, in my_func
    inherited.func()
  File "test.py", line 8, in func
    cls.params
AttributeError: type object 'inherited' has no attribute 'params'
```

Why is it not able to find `params` in this case?

Comment: `attr.ib()` makes it an instance attribute, not a class attribute. Class methods only have access to class attributes, since there's no `self`.

Answer (score 0):

You have abused the `attrs` library by accessing a class attribute defined as a placeholder for an instance attribute. That pattern is not and should not be supported by the `attrs`. Original class attributes used for placeholders are removed by the decorator `attr.s`.

You can see that from the following example.

```
import attr

def probe_cls(prefix):
    def not_wrap(cls):
        print(prefix, hasattr(cls, 'a'))
        return cls
    return not_wrap

@probe_cls('after:')
@attr.s
@probe_cls('before:')
class X:
    a = attr.ib()
```

This will output the following.

```
before: True
after: False
```

For details, see [the official document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) for the class decorator, and [the wrapping implementation](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/22.2.0/src/attr/_make.py#L1481).

As a side note, I recommend to use the modern API such as `attrs.define`.